# Scrollbar versus arrow in FireFox & ThunderBird

Tags: firefox, mouse, thunderbird, scrollbar

I have this problem scrolling in FireFox & ThinderBird: when I click on the scroll-arrow with the left mouse-button, the page scrolls incrementally. If I click on the scrollbar instead, the page jumps to the location of the cursor. Ironically, if I click on the scrollbar with the right button, the page moves incrementally, but if I us the rightl button to click on the arrow then the page jumps to the top or bottom (depending on which arrow I clicked on).

Note that this is a big problem if I let the cursor slip onto or off of the arrow position. Then the page can jump to the current cursor location and I lose the place where I was looking at the page.

I don't want it to work that way. I'd like the left button the scroll incrementally whether I click on the arrow or the bar (perhaps scrolling to different degrees) and the right (or middle) button to jump the page to the location of the cursor whether I click on the arrow or the bar.

That way I wouldn't lose the place I was looking at. Left==incremental and Right==absolute, regardless of whether I click on the arrow or the bar.

I have my mouse set to left-handed. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
Is there a setting inside the FireFox/ThunderBird about.config that I can use to control this?

Comment: WIth Chrome, I can use the left-hand button to scroll incrementally with both the scroll-arrow and the scroll-bar, and the middle mouse-button to jump to the cursor location on the scoll-bar. This is the way FireFox and ThinderBird used to work for me.

Somehow this got lost in the new version of Ubuntu. I think I had to fiddle with the some configuration file in order to even get the scroll-arrows to show up. This may have to do with the reason they also behave differently.

Comment: Note also that the middle mouse-button on FireFox & ThunderBird doesn't do anything when I click on the scroll-bar. I can use it on the scroll-arrow to scroll incrementally the same as the left-button does.